# I have a problem with redirection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am new to react and i am creating a simple Contact Manager App, i have contacts and addContact components, these are separated in different routes.
When i add a contact,it gets added to the local storage and the contacts component is getting the list of contacts from the local storage.
The problem that when i add a contact and  i redirect to the contacts page, the new contact doesn't show unless i manually refresh the page.

i tried this :

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

this too

```
window.location.href=window.location.hostname;
```

and i created a function to refresh the page if the previous link is the addContact link, it doesn't work either

this is the App component code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Contacts from './components/contacts';
import About from './components/pages/about';
import AddContact from './components/pages/addContact'
import NotFound from './components/pages/notFound'

function getContactsLS() {
    let contacts;
    if (localStorage.getItem('contacts') === null) {
        contacts = [];
    }
    else {
        contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
    }
    contacts = Array.from(contacts);
    return contacts;
}


class App extends React.Component {
    contactsLS = getContactsLS();

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="container">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/add-contact" component={AddContact} />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Contacts contacts={this.contactsLS} />} />
                        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

this is addContact function :

```js
addContactEvent = () =>{
        let contacts;
        if(localStorage.getItem('contacts')===null)
            contacts=[];
        else{
            contacts=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
        }
        contacts=Array.from(contacts);
        console.log(contacts);
        this.setState({key:contacts.length});
        const contact = {
            key : contacts.length,
            name: this.state.name,
            email:this.state.email,
            phone:this.state.phone
        }
        contacts.push(contact);
        localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts));

        //redirection
        //this.props.history.push('/');
        window.location.href=window.location.hostname;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you also show your getContacts page code?

Comment: tell us what router you are using and show us that code as well. you should be using a method from the router you use to change pages like a `Link` component.

Comment: Try this: `window.location.assign('/');` or `window.location.assign(window.location.hostname);`

Comment: @NN796 i tried but still doesn't work :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you would want the contacts as part of the state. In that case the code would be:

```
state = { contactLS: getContactsLS()}
```

But as we are calling values from localStorage a more appropriate place might be
`componentDidMount()` method.From react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the
>   constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

Then the code would be

```
componentDidMount(){
    const contacts =  getContactsLS()
    this.setState({ contacsLS: contacts })
}
```

Don't forget to change to **this.state.contactsLS**

```
<Route exact path="/" component={() => <Contacts contacts={this.state.contactsLS} />} />
```

====

PS
Another problem i can see in the existing code is the misuse of component constructor.
This is not obvious but the line

```
contactsLS = getContactsLS();
```

is equivalent to

```
constrcutor(){
   this.contactLS = getContactLS();
}
```

from react documentation we [read](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>   - Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
>   - Binding
>   event handler methods to an instance.

Comment: the '/' path is for contacts page, using the code you suggested in the App component is not needed.thank you for the constructor note

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<Redirect>` component from `react-router-dom` package. To get it working you initially setState where redirect is set to false.

```
this.state = {
  redirect: false
}
```

Once the `addContact` opeartion is done, update the state

```
this.setState({
  redirect: true
})
```

Inside of your `AddContact` component, the state will decide if it has to show the actual component or to redirect to the attached path.
Something like this:

```
import {Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class AddContact extends React.Component {
  //Add the initial state
  // addContact Operation
  render(){
    if(this.state.redirect)
      return <Redirect to="/" />
    return (
       //The markup for AddContact
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: same thing, it does redirect but still do not update the contacts